# Reset values from react-hook-form when the form is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Having the following component:

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import { useToggle } from '../shared/hooks';
import {
  SubsectionLayout,
  Footer,
  Textarea,
  Input,
  Modal,
  Button
} from '../shared/ui-components';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  description: yup.string().required()
});

export interface ITask {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

export function MainComponent() {
  const [isOpened, toggleModal] = useToggle(false);

  const { handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: ITask) => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
    toggleModal();
    reset(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleModal} />
      <SubsectionLayout title='test'>
        <Modal
          title='add element'
          open={isOpened}
          onClose={toggleModal}
          footer={
            <Footer onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} onCancel={toggleModal} editMode={true} />
          }
        >
          <div>
            <Input
              inputId='calculation-engine-script-name'
              label='name'
              {...register('name')}
            />

            <Textarea label='description' {...register('description')} />
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </SubsectionLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MainComponent;
```

It has a button, when clicked it opens a modal where a user can write inside `name` and `description` fields.

When the submit button is clicked it must log the content (for testing purpose) and close the modal.

The problem is that when I open again the modal, the input that was introduced before is still there.

I added `reset(data)` inside `onSubmit()` but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reset the values with the values you get when the form is submitted. Shouldn't it be something like `reset()`?

Comment: @RameshReddy I've tried like that but same result

Comment: did u try `reset({ name: '', description: '' });` ?

Comment: [official react-hook-form docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) in 'submit with reset'  they have simply added `reset({ ...data });`

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake, your first comment has the correct solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `reset({ name: '', description: '' });`